# Are transcendent species inherently off-topic/opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

This question:  [The right mix of emotions for a civilization that is not concerned about reproducing but spreading itself throughout the universe?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98069/the-right-mix-of-emotions-for-a-civilization-that-is-not-concerned-about-reprodu)  has been put on hold as too broad.  Key quote from the comments:

> The problem is, there is no real way for us to know how such a transcendent species would feel, us being mired in this flesh with its biological urges. Therefore, any number of answers could be correct. Since SE is a Q & A site, and this question doesn't have a 'correct' answer, it is too broad for this site. I'd suggest that you make a proposal about these transcendentally-emotive beings and then ask people to explain why it does work

I'm afraid that even if OP were to follow the fixit advice (and many props to @kingledion for including some!) the question would be immediately closed as opinion-based.

So ... is there any way to get this question whipped into shape, or are our "sublimed" friends just SOL on SE?

Let me rephrase this...

> I'm asking whether any question touching on this subject would be similarly considered opinion-based. Say OP took kingledion's advice and said, "Transcendent beings have these emotions, amirite?"... VTCers could reasonably make the exact same argument for closing, that any answer would be opinion-based. I'm not liking this, but I'm feeling a sense of grinding inevitability about it...

**Update:  We're going to try it.  Similar question in (I hope) a slant which will not be closed.  [Will these transcendent beings be friendly, chatty social magpies?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98211/will-these-transcendent-beings-be-friendly-chatty-social-magpies) .  We'll see.**

Answer (score 2):

Kingledion got it right.

Unfortunately, **unless the main question is changed**, answers would be equally right. That doesn't make this *too broad*, but **opinion-based**.

If the main question (What would be the perfect mix of emotions ...) changed, then we can consider to reopen that question.

Comment: I'm not (yet, gimme a bit) asking to reopen the question.  I'm asking whether **any** question touching on this subject would be similarly considered opinion-based.  Say OP took kingledion's advice and said, "Transcendent beings have these emotions, amirite?"...  VTCers could reasonably make the *exact same argument* for closing, that any answer would be opinion-based.  I'm not liking this, but I'm feeling a sense of grinding inevitability about it...

Comment: @akaioi the question on your body does not imply that, only the title. I suggest you change that.

Comment: @akaioi any question *touching* this issue does not necessarily too opinion-based. It must be dealt case-by-case. It all depends on the main question and how it is presented. A well presented question might be allowed to tread the fine line between on and off topic, or too broad, or opinion-based.

Comment: Vylix let's see.  Look at this meta question's update, I've posted a similar question which I hope will pass muster.  Call it a thought experiment.